# MySQL - Combining the max and concat functions

Tags: mysql, sql, max, string-concatenation

My SQL table has information on book titles, and I want to select the book that has the highest price, and I also want to display 'The most expensive book costs $xx.xx’

Here is the code of the table

```
CREATE TABLE titles
  (
  title_id   CHAR(3)      NOT NULL,
  title_name VARCHAR(40)  NOT NULL,
  type       VARCHAR(10)          ,
  pub_id     CHAR(3)      NOT NULL,
  pages      INTEGER              ,
  price      DECIMAL(5,2)         ,
  sales      INTEGER              ,
  pubdate    DATE                 ,
  contract   SMALLINT     NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_titles PRIMARY KEY (title_id)
  )ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I have tried the code below and it does not work.

```
SELECT CONCAT(MAX('The most expensive book costs ', price)) FROM titles;
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `CONCAT` incorrectly.

```
SELECT CONCAT('The most expensive book costs ', "$", MAX(price)) AS MaxPrice 
FROM titles;
```

Fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85668/1/0